# Linq query get sum from list where certain property equals to

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have the following class:

**Activity**

- Time (int)
- Checked (char)

Example list:

Activity 1:
Time=5 Checked=y

Activity 2:
Time=5 Checked=n

Activity 3:
Time=5 Checked=y

In my list of activities, I want to select the total time in minutes for the activities that have the checked value 'y'.

In the case above my total should be 10.

I used the following:

```
int minutes =  i.Activities.Sum(i.Activities.Where(x => x.Checked == 'y'));
```

This returns

> 'cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
>   to System.Func'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `i.Activities.Where(x => x.Checked == 'y').Sum()`

Comment: @KahnKah, if Erik's suggestion doesn't work, I would then ask if you can post a minimum working example: one that compiles, runs  and demonstrates the error. It may give more insight into your issue and will allow others to run your problem and work out solutions.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I try to provide enough info to fix the problem described, not solve the complete problem.  This lets people still work out for themselves the full details, with just a little help.  I prefer to encourage critical thinking skills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to filter the results beforehand:

```
int minutes =  i.Activities.Where(x => x.Checked == 'y').Sum(x => x.Time);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this